# Help with leipzig glossaries on TexShop with xelatexmk

Tags: glossaries, latexmk, leipzig

I'm having trouble getting a glossary (with the `leipzig` package) to print. I use TeXShop on the Mac with `xelatexmk`.

The MWE uses the style from the `leipzig` manual:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatexmk
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nomain,section=chapter]{glossaries}%
 \usepackage{glossary-inline}%
 \newglossarystyle{mysuper}{%
 \glossarystyle{super}% based on super
   \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\tablehead{}\tabletail{}%
      \begin{supertabular}{@{}lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
     {\end{supertabular}}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
     \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}
       & \makefirstuc{##3}\glspostdescription{}\\}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
      &
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
      \glstarget{##2}{\strut}\makefirstuc{##4}\glspostdescription{}\\}%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}%
\usepackage{leipzig}%
\makeglossaries
\glsdisablehyper

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=mysuper,type=\leipzigtype]
Testing Leipzig {\Aarg} {\Pst} {\Det}
\end{document}
```

I've followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175511/how-to-create-the-latexmkrc-file) and edited `~/Library/TeXShop/bin/latexmkrcedit`, adding the lines from the answer  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries):

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}
```

However, it still doesn't bring up the glossary, so I assume I did something wrong. Any help much appreciated.

*EDIT:*  I have added the above lines to both `~/Library/TeXShop/bin/latexmkrcedit` and `~/.latexmkrc` but no success. I do get a warning about no file `testfile.lzs` and a deprecated command `\glossarystyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your document, glossary type is leipzig, for which the glossary files are `lzs` and `lzo`.  So you need the corresponding custom dependency.  In the `latexmkrc` file (which is in your case `~/Library/TeXShop/bin/latexmkrcedit`), add the line

```
add_cus_dep('lzo', 'lzs', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
```

Comment: Fantastic!   You saved me!

Comment: In case someone tries this with leipzig 2.0 (just added to CTAN, 2017-06-16), this is not always the case anymore. Gloss abbreviations are put into the main glossary by default ('glo', 'gls'). Only if you use the package option [glosses] will they be put into a glossary type=leipzig ('lzo', 'lzs'). Probably the safest action is to add lines for all of the above.